# Accessing reverse relationship gives a TypeError in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

I have a model that has a foreign key to another model. Upon trying to access it using reverse relationship I get `TypeError at / 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. This is relationship between the two models.

```
Class Person(models.Model):
    #field declarations

Class Phone(models.Model): 
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Upon grabbing a Person object (lets say p), doing p.phone_set.all() I get the following:

```
/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in all(self)
    189         # implementation of `RelatedManager.get_queryset()` for a better
    190         # understanding of how this comes into play.
--> 191         return self.get_queryset()
    192
    193

/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in get_queryset(self)
    659         def get_queryset(self):
    660             try:
--> 661                 return self.instance._prefetched_objects_cache[rel_field.related_query_name()]
    662             except (AttributeError, KeyError):
    663                 db = self._db or router.db_for_read(self.model, instance=self.instance)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Am I doing something wrong or could this be a django 1.7 bug?

Edit: Full traceback on the browser:

```
Traceback:
File "/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  103.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  79.         context = self.resolve_context(self.context_data)
File "/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_context
  156.         return RequestContext(self._request, context, current_app=self._current_app)
File "/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py" in _request_context__init__
  55.         context = processor(request)
File "/work/root/ease_dental/context_processors.py" in practice_info
  69.         phonenumbers = p.phone_set.all()
File "/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in all
  191.         return self.get_queryset()
File "/work/root/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in get_queryset
  661.                 return self.instance._prefetched_objects_cache[rel_field.related_query_name()]

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: It's pretty unlikely there'd be a bug in such a critical part of the orm. But you haven't shown what you were doing, and you've stripped off half the traceback.

Comment: Thats a valid point regarding django bug. The traceback I posted was  the full traceback I got in the shell. But I just added the traceback from the browser. Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: how are you grabbing a person object?  Can you check it's not None?

Comment: Person.objects.get(pk=1) and nope it is not none.